# How to associate new project and already downloaded NuGet packages?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget, visual-studio-2017

How to easily associate a new project and already downloaded NuGet packages?

An example scenario:

I created a Visual Studio solution and project, named `mylib`. And I installed Nuget packages, like C++ boost library. I can use the boost library right away without setting header/linker directories manually. This is very convenient.

Now I create a new project (or add an existing project) under the same solution, named `executable`. I also want to use the boost library in this project.

Unfortunately, there is no graphical or IDE interface to link the dependency for the new project.

[image]

The above picture shows NuGet packages are installed, but newly added project `executable` still don't have links.

To correct this, I have to manually modify the project (e.g., .vcxproj) XML file. I copied from `mylib` and pasted it to `executable`.

```
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
    <Import Project="packages\boost.1.65.1.0\build\native\boost.targets" Condition="Exists('packages\boost.1.65.1.0\build\native\boost.targets')" />
    <Import Project="packages\boost_regex-vc141.1.65.1.0\build\native\boost_regex-vc141.targets" Condition="Exists('packages\boost_regex-vc141.1.65.1.0\build\native\boost_regex-vc141.targets')" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('packages\boost.1.65.1.0\build\native\boost.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', 'packages\boost.1.65.1.0\build\native\boost.targets'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('packages\boost_regex-vc141.1.65.1.0\build\native\boost_regex-vc141.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', 'packages\boost_regex-vc141.1.65.1.0\build\native\boost_regex-vc141.targets'))" />
  </Target>
```

It works then.

Or, uninstalling already downloaded NuGet packages and reinstalling them also works. But that's obviously not a good solution.

I'm wondering if there is a nice way to re-associate dependency between already downloaded NuGet packages and projects. I was unable to find such feature in the project property pages in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Have you also installed the nuget package `boost` to the project `executable`? How did you added it, Is it the same as adding to the `mylib` project? To re-associate dependency between already downloaded NuGet packages and projects, you can use the command line `Update-Package -Id <package_name> –reinstall 
` in the Package Manager Console window.

Comment: @Leo-MSFT Thanks for the comment! I could be wrong, but I was unable to install `boost` to the `executable` project. As the screen capture shows, `executable` is shown to have already `boost`. BTW, `Update-Package` seems work! That's what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To correct this, I have to manually modify the project (e.g., .vcxproj) XML file. I copied from mylib and pasted it to executable

According to your description, that seems the package `boost` has not been installed properly to the project `executable`. So you can use the NuGet command line in the Package Manager Console:

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```

to force reinstall the package to the `executable` project.